# Compare a list of numbers with another to get longest consecutive string

Tags: matlab, vector

I have an original order of numbers:

```
x = [2 6 4 3 6 3 4 6 2 6 3 4 2];
```

And I would like to compare a new vector of numbers:

```
y = [6 4 2 6 3 4 6 2 6 3 2 4 2 2 6 2];
```

to the original to get the longest consecutive string of similar numbers. So in the example above, the longest consecutive string will be

```
6 3 4 6 2 6 3
```

Thank you!

Comment: This problem is known as the longest common substring.  The best way to do this would be using dynamic programming.  Read the duplicate I linked above to get started.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know about the duplication and sorry about it. Anyway, I have managed to write my own code with the help of another code written by someone else. Thanks!